# Viable hardware for Kafka brokers

Tags: apache-kafka

I find it hard to find information on what hardware Kafka requires. For instance, what DigitalOcean instance would be suitable for a Kafka broker? I understand that a big one will handle it, but I'd like to have the smallest one that performs well and scale horizontally.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it's looking for hardware recommendations, rather than programming help.

Comment: @DonRoby How would you recommend I frame it, so that I achieve my goal of knowing what kind of processing power is needed per Kafka broker?

Comment: I don't know a way to frame it so that it fits on this site.  This site is for programming questions.  Perhaps there's another site where you can ask, but I don't know where that is.  Nor do I know an answer.

Comment: I think you're being a bit narrow-minded here, to be honest. Software does not live in clean separation from deployment, there is sometimes an overlap. That is why we have a field called devops.

Comment: This question is not about hardware, it is about how much memory and disk space a specific piece of software needs. It would be ridiculous to ask in a hardware forum.

Comment: I think  this guy says it very well: http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/253654

Comment: @MattiasPetterJohansson how could we come up with an answer without knowing your workload requirements?

Comment: @om-nom-nom After being met with the general "attack the question" welcome you get on SO, I asked this question on Quora and got two constructive responses instead of people bickering about whether or not the question was valid. Here is a great one: 
http://www.quora.com/What-is-viable-hardware-for-Zookeeper-and-Kafka-brokers/answer/Jack-Mehoff-26

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Any of them. Kafka itself is a java process, so to run it you need enough memory to support a JVM and the kafka process itself. You're going to get that with any of the Digital Ocean host sizes.

A kafka host generally ends up saturating its network connection before reaching problems with RAM, CPU, or disk I/O. How that's going to play out in a shared infrastructure situation is more or less impossible to predict from the outside.